# binding to a blob in blobtriggered function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

**How do we bind to properties inside of a blob?**

My bindings:

```
    public static async Task Run(
        [BlobTrigger("%triggerContainer%/{name}")] Stream myBlob,
        [Blob("%triggerContainer%/{name}", Read)]  CloudBlockBlob @in,
        [Blob("%outputContainer%/{name}", Write)] CloudBlockBlob @out,
        string name, ILogger log)
    {
```

I'd like to be able to change the blobtrigger type to a POCO:

```
[BlobTrigger("%triggerContainer%/{name}")] MyPoco myBlob
```

Where `MyPoco` might be something like this:

```
public class MyPoco
{
   public string id {get;set;}
   public string filename {get;set;}
}
```

From within the function I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
var thisId = myBlob.id;
var thisfileName = myBlob.filename;
```

**How do we bind to the actual contents of the blob with a POCO object?**

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp):

> JavaScript and Java functions load the entire blob into memory, and C#
>   functions do that if you bind to string, Byte[], or POCO.

Comment: Interesting - I have just tried and get an error like: `The 'Function1' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind BlobTrigger to type 'FunctionApp6.MyPoco'.` - is that what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write an IExtensionConfigProvider that registers converters as needed,

```
internal class CustomBlobConverterExtensionConfigProvider : IExtensionConfigProvider
{
    public void Initialize(ExtensionConfigContext context)
    {
        context.AddConverter<Stream, MyPoco>(s =>
        {
            // read and convert
            return new MyPoco();
        });

        context.AddConverter<ApplyConversion<MyPoco, Stream>, object>(p =>
        {
            MyPoco value = p.Value;
            var stream = p.Existing;

            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            // write the value to the stream
            writer.FlushAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

Then, you register this config provider with the host builder on startup:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
        .AddAzureStorage()
        .AddExtension<CustomBlobConverterExtensionConfigProvider>();
    })
```

Then bind your BlobTrigger function to Mypoco:

```
public void BlobTrigger([BlobTrigger("test")] Mypoco item, ILogger logger)
{
    // process item
}
```

For more information, have a look of [this doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings).

Comment: cha chiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiing